# MacBook not getting internet access on district network

Tags: macbook-pro, network, macos, wifi

I'm the new guy at my school district's Tech Department and we have a closed network where only domained machines, and ones we add, can have wireless access. We've added my account and MAC address to the system and my MacBook still won't connect wirelessly and i'm beginning to think it's my MacBook somehow because it does connect on a single AP at the Tech Office. Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: If it’s only not working on your Mac and only on one the the access points then it would seem reasonable that it’s a configuration issue between them but if your access points all have identical configurations and your Mac works on the other ones then there is just as much chance the Mac is causing the issue as the access point and it would seem to me to be easier to ractory reset and reconfigure the access point than your Mac. However if you have an external hard drive going spare you could install macOS onto the external drive from fresh so you can check it’s not a macOS software issue.

Comment: When you say “domained ” machines, do you mean a machine that has a OU container on the AD domain controller?